# Using the state in a let in a do block in Haskell

Tags: haskell, state-monad

I have the following data structure and function:

```
data BTree a = BLeaf | BNode (BTree a) a (BTree a) deriving (Show, Eq)
freshNodesS :: BTree String -> State [String] (BTree String)
freshNodesS BLeaf = return BLeaf
freshNodesS (BNode l m r) = do  l' <- freshNodesS l
                                let m' = getFresh m s
                                let s' = m : s
                                r' <- freshNodesS r s'
                                return (BNode l' m' r')
```

There is this problem that I actually want to use the state from `freshNodesS l` which should give an output of `(BTree String, [String])`, but in a do block I can't use `(l', s) <- freshNodesS l`, the only option I see is placing everything in an lambda function.
But is there a way I still can use the do notation?

---

After what @chi said I did this:

```
freshNodesS BLeaf           = return BLeaf
freshNodesS (BNode l m r)   = do    l' <- freshNodesS l
                                    m' <- getFreshS m
                                    r' <- freshNodesS r
                                    return (BNode l' m' r')
                    
getFreshS :: String -> State [String] String
getFreshS x = state $ (\s -> let newx = getFresh x s in (newx, newx: s))
```

And that worked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole point of the `State` monad is to automatically pass states around, without you having to do that explicitly. Almost no function should get `s` as argument, or return it.

For instance,

```
let m' = getFresh m s
```

is suspicious, it should probably read

```
m' <- getFresh m
```

where we would have `getFresh :: String -> State [String] String`.

The whole code should then read as

```
       do l' <- freshNodesS l
          m' <- getFresh m
          r' <- freshNodesS r
          return (BNode l' m' r')
```

Note how no `s` or `s'` is ever mentioned. This should look like imperative code, where a mutable state variable is modified by each function call, even if the code does not mention that explicitly.

Now, in `getFresh` you will have to deal with the states, since there's no way around that. If your `State` monad is the standard one, you can access the state with `get` and `put`. You probably need something like

```
getFresh :: String -> State [String] String
getFresh m = do
   s <- get          -- read the current state
   let m' = ...      -- compute a fresh name m'
   let s' = m' : s   -- mark m' as used
   put s'            -- write the current state
   return m'
```

Answer (score 3):

do-notation is just syntactic sugar rewriting `<-` binds with `>>=` binds and lambdas. If you can write it with one, you can write it with the other. So, if you think you can write this with lambdas, I encourage you to do so. Then, rewrite it to use do-notation, and you will have learned something. But I suspect you will run into the same stumbling block, because as I say there is actually nothing special about using lambdas instead of do-notation.

It's hard for me to say what you meant to write, because you do not give a type signature for `getFresh`. It's a bit puzzling that this function takes a state in as a direct argument, instead of participating in the State monad like the rest of your program. I suggest rewriting it to have signature

```
getFresh :: String -> State [String] String
getFresh m = do {...}
```

You will of course have to change the implementation, for which I recommend you look into the `get` and `put` operations. But having made this change, your `freshNodesS` function will be liberated from having to do any manual threading-through of the state parameter, as it will be entirely handled by the State machinery, as intended:

```
freshNodesS (BNode l m r) = do
  l' <- freshNodesS l
  m' <- getFresh m
  r' <- freshNodesS r
  return (BNode l' m' r')
```

Or, you could write this in applicative style instead:

```
freshNodesS (BNode l m r) = 
  BNode <$> freshNodesS l <*> getFresh m <*> freshNodesS r
```

This way you make it clear none of the three operations depend on each other aside from sharing the same state, and you don't need to gives names to variables that don't do much.